# Is there docker commands for external Repository?

Tags: docker, artifactory

I tried some REST API requests to fetch the rocker images and tags , but like to understand if there is any custom docker commands ? I see there is something on the line like “docker repository ls” , but not sure . Can anyone help ?

Comment: What is you goal? Do you just want to push/pull a certain image?

Answer (score -1):

I found a read on the docker documentation that docker is coming up with command line option in their enterprise edition which would help to list down the images from external registry

docker registry ls REPOSITORY[:TAG] [OPTIONS]

Reference link as below . Good one to read
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/registry_ls/